# Hbase is not allowing to populate data using JAVA API

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to populate data in hbase table using Java API but data is not being inserted into the table.Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create(); 
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.133.4:2181");
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.133.5:2181");
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.133.3:2181");

    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
    config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.133.3:60010"); 
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns", "1000");

    System.out.println("HBase is running!");
    HTable table = new HTable(config, "manish_hash_table");
    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("11"));

    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("hash_id"), Bytes.toBytes("h11"));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("chunk_order"), Bytes.toBytes("11"));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("chunk_usage"), Bytes.toBytes("1"));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("s3_link"), Bytes.toBytes("hash11.com"));

    table.put(p);

    Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1"));
    Result r = table.get(g);
    byte[] value = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("hash_id"));
    String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);
    System.out.println("GET: " + valueStr); 
}
```

when i run this a lot of warning is coming and that is being continued. 
Warning looks like

```
HBase is running!
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=manish
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_67
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_67/jre
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/hadoop/workspace/Hbase/bin:/usr/local/hbase/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hbase-0.90.2.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/org-apache-commons-codec.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/jsr177.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/aws-java-sdk.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/framework_S3.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/com.google.common.source_1.0.0.201004262004.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hbase-client-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hbase-common-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/hbase-it-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar:/home/hadoop/Downloads/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.13.0-40-generic
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hadoop
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hadoop
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hadoop/workspace/Hbase
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.133.153:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 192.168.133.153/192.168.133.153:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 192.168.133.153/192.168.133.153:2181, initiating session
14/11/29 16:15:18 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 192.168.133.153/192.168.133.153:2181, sessionid = 0x149ae215d500058, negotiated timeout = 40000
```

Please Help me. I am completely new in Hadoop and Hbase.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the output you posted there is no warning... just some info about the environment and the notification about the successful connection to zookeeper.

from the code you are trying to insert `"11"` and reading `"1"` which will never return the `"11"` you probably are expecting...

```
Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("11"));  
Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1"));
```

Comment: Thanks. but data for row "1" is already there in Hbase(I added it through Shell CLI).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a connection to Hbase.
You need to create a connection to hbase using your config 
HConnectionManager.createConnection(config)